# Excel Escaping Single and double quotes

Tags: excel, vba, replace, excel-formula, double-quotes

I have a formula in each cell in excel where I need to edit.  But I am having a hard time escaping the single quotes and double quotes using VBA code.

This is an example:

```
=+'F-222Alloc'!N2516+'F-222Alloc'!N2526
```

I need it to look like this

```
=+INDIRECT("'"&N14&"'!N2511")+INDIRECT("'"&N14&"'!N2526")
```

How do I use the REPLACE function properly?

Comment: Is there a typo, or do you want to replace `N2516` in the first with `N2511` in the second?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I find the easiest is to define a variable that contains just the double quote - then use it like any other string. Makes the code much more readable.  Example:

```
Dim dq As String, sq as string
dq = Chr(34) ' double quote as a variable
sq = Chr(39) ' apostrophe or single quote as variable
Dim sourceString As String
sourceString = "hello"
msgbox sq + sourceString + "! " + dq + "you" + dq + sq
```

With these two variables you can create any string you want - after that, replacing what you want with something else (that might contain a crazy sequence of `"'"'"'"("!"'")` for all I care) becomes trivial.

Some helpful rules can be found in [this article](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/msoffice/5-rules-for-embedding-strings-in-vba-code/4687)